# How can i make programs work in background in Linux mint?

Tags: linux, themes, customization, panel, background-application

i have a new issue when i was trying to make my Linux-mint more beautiful  for example when i open telegram and then when i click on close button of telegram it get closed and i need to open again and this is annoying , it wasn't like this it was open in the background and i could access from my top panel now the top panel access is totally gone after i change some panel setting and try some new themes  need help TY so much

this is my Linux as u can see telegram is not in the top panel so if i just suddenly click on exit button it get close and i need to open again i just want it to go to background
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W91AV.png

Answer (score 0):

OK guys here's the answer , i was trying to restore setting to previous so i just right click on my panel and then troubleshooting then click on restore all setting to default
now it is fix Good luck
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU2yK.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).